# Passing multiple parameters to API

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, web-services

I have a program written in java which reads 2 `json` file from `classpath`. I have been told to create same program for `RestAPI`.

Whenever I created `postAPI` I passed data from body. How can I send data of more than one file in `postAPI`.

is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to receive the data as separate files from the backend, you can implement an API that supports multipart uploads.

e.g.: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload